# Shuffling deck of cards

Tags: java

I am having trouble constructing the shuffle part of my program to shuffle a deck of cards. I just need help constructing the shuffle part. The errors I'm getting are that it can't find "symbol: varible suit"

```
package playingcard;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

public class Pack {

    PlayingCard[] cards = new PlayingCard[52];
    public int counter = 0;

    /**
     * Constructs a pack of 52 cards. Sorted by suit Clubs, Diamonds, Hearts,
     * Spades. Sorted ascending.
     */
    public void Pack() {

        // Intialising array
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < PlayingCard.Suit.values().length; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < PlayingCard.Rank.values().length; j++) {
                    PlayingCard.Suit suit = PlayingCard.Suit.values()[i];
                    PlayingCard.Rank rank = PlayingCard.Rank.values()[j];
                    cards[counter] = new PlayingCard(suit, rank);
                    counter++;
                }
            }
        }

    }

    /**
     * Shuffles cards in pack.
     */
    public void shuffle() {

        for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++) {
           Random random = new Random();
            int rand = random.nextInt(50)+1;
            cards[counter] = PlayingCard(suit, rank);

        }
    }

    /**
     * @return string representation of 52 card pack.
     */
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your exact question? Please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve): **Describe the problem.** "It doesn't work" is not a problem statement. Tell us what the expected behavior should be. Tell us what the exact wording of the error message is, and which line of code is producing it. Put a brief summary of the problem in the title of your question.

Comment: You could create an another (initially empty) array for the shuffled cards and then add each card from the original deck there from random indexes. The task will become simpler if you use dynamic collections (`List`s); then you can simply `remove()` from random indexes from the source and `add()` to the destination `while (source.size() > 0)`.

Comment: How would you do that??

Comment: Did you write this code? Where's the rest? It looks like you are just trying to copy homework and I'd love to be proved wrong.

Comment: `Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(cards));`

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is you're trying to have multiple methods have access to the same
variable. The way to do this is to declare that variable right after the class declaration,
just like you declared your cards variable. This way all the methods will have acces and you
won't get that error. Here's the fixed code.

```
public class  Pack{

PlayingCard[] cards = new PlayingCard[52];
PlayingCard.Suit suit;
PlayingCard.Rank rank;
public int counter = 0;

/**
 * Constructs a pack of 52 cards. Sorted by suit Clubs, Diamonds, Hearts,
 * Spades. Sorted ascending.
 */
public void Pack() {

    // Intialising array
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < PlayingCard.Suit.values().length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < PlayingCard.Rank.values().length; j++) {
                suit = PlayingCard.Suit.values()[i];
                rank = PlayingCard.Rank.values()[j];
                cards[counter] = new PlayingCard(suit, rank);
                counter++;
            }
        }
    }

}

/**
 * Shuffles cards in pack.
 */
public void shuffle() {

    for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++) {
       Random random = new Random();
        int rand = random.nextInt(50)+1;
        cards[counter] = PlayingCard(suit, rank);

    }
}

/**
 * @return string representation of 52 card pack.
 */
@Override
public String toString() {
    return null;
}
```

}